# gRPC gradle :generateProto fails with directory not found when importing other proto definitions

Tags: gradle, vert.x, grpc-java

I'm trying to compile some protobuf definitions as a gradle task, but get the following error with no source generation:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateProto'.
> protoc: stdout: . stderr: /Users/ash/IdeaProjects/kotlin/grpc/build/extracted-protos/main: warning: directory does not exist.
  service-definitions.proto:10:17: "Empty" is not defined.
  service-definitions.proto:10:33: "Empty" is not defined.
  service-definitions.proto:15:17: "SimpleRequest" is not defined.
  service-definitions.proto:15:41: "SimpleResponse" is not defined.
  service-definitions.proto:21:27: "StreamingOutputCallRequest" is not defined.
  service-definitions.proto:21:71: "StreamingOutputCallResponse" is not defined.
  service-definitions.proto:27:33: "StreamingInputCallRequest" is not defined.
  service-definitions.proto:27:69: "StreamingInputCallResponse" is not defined.
  service-definitions.proto:34:29: "StreamingOutputCallRequest" is not defined.
  service-definitions.proto:34:73: "StreamingOutputCallResponse" is not defined.
  service-definitions.proto: warning: Import empty.proto but not used.
  service-definitions.proto: warning: Import messages.proto but not used.
```

This only occurs when I try to compile a definition that imports other definitions. If I remove the `service-definitions.proto` definition, the others compile and sources are generated.

The protobuf definitions are available from the [vertx-grpc examples](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/6647064e8a7afab08fa1165c3a55581ebdbb6cd2/grpc-examples) and I have them in `$projectDir/src/main/proto`. I've not changed their default build location, so sources are being generated to `$projectDir/build/generated/source/proto`. Instead of an `extracted-protos` directory, however, I have `extracted-include-protos` (probably explains the directory not found error).

Here's my `gradle.build` file, should it be of use. Note that the gRPC plugin uses the Vert.x artifact rather than the version from `io.grpc..` (it's actually just a wrapper over the top of it). I have tried swapping the Vert.x version out for the `io.grpc` version and get the same error.

```
group 'grpc'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "com.google.protobuf"
apply plugin: "idea"

protobuf {
    //generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/build/generated/source/proto"
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.3.0"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.vertx:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.3.0"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins {
                grpc {}
            }
        }
    }
}

clean {
    delete protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/java")
        sourceDirs += file("${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/grpc")
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs += "${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/java"
            srcDirs += "${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/grpc"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "io.vertx:vertx-core:3.4.2"
    compile "io.vertx:vertx-web:3.4.2"
    compile "io.vertx:vertx-grpc:3.4.2"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        apiVersion = "1.1"
        languageVersion = "1.1"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        apiVersion = "1.1"
        languageVersion = "1.1"
    }
}
```

I've not changed any settings, why is it (a) looking for extracted files in the wrong location, and (b) looking for extracted files at all when importing, given that the necessary definitions are all in the `src/main/proto` directory?

Comment: Full source is available at my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/AshleyByeUK/grpc) if it helps provide clarity or to enable the issue to be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after much head scratching, the clue was in the last two lines of the error message:

```
service-definitions.proto: warning: Import empty.proto but not used.
service-definitions.proto: warning: Import messages.proto but not used.
```

In my proto definitions, I had specified `messages` and `empty` to be in the `messages` package but hadn't qualified the types when used in the importing definition, which is in the `services` package. Alas, a simple change and it works:

```
package services;
service EmptyPingPongService {
  // One empty request followed by one empty response.
  rpc EmptyCall(Empty) returns (Empty);
}
```

Becomes:

```
package services;    
service EmptyPingPongService {
  // One empty request followed by one empty response.
  rpc EmptyCall(messages.Empty) returns (messages.Empty);
}
```